# Filtering multi-dimensional array based on another array elements

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays in the code below - which `matches` is the main one and the other `played` which serves it is purpose for elements to filter out in the main array:

```
var matches = [[1,4],[3,1],[5,2],[3,4],[4,5],[2,1]];
var played = [2,5];
```

I need to filter out elements in matches based on played array, which means if there is any 2 or 5 in, then remove it altogether. Also the played array can be any length, min is 1.

Expected output should be

```
[[1,4],[3,1],[3,4]];
```

So I have tried this piece of code, but it doesn't yield the result I want.

```
var result = matches.map(x => x.filter(e => played.indexOf(e) < 0))
```

So anyway to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check with `some` and exclude the unwanted arrays.

```js
var matches = [[1, 4], [3, 1], [5, 2], [3, 4], [4, 5], [2, 1]],
    played = [2, 5],
    result = matches.filter(a => !a.some(v => played.includes(v)));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

While filtering, check that `.every` one of the subarray elements are not included in `[2, 5]`:

```js
var matches = [[1,4],[3,1],[5,2],[3,4],[4,5],[2,1]];
var played = [2,5];

const result = matches.filter(
  subarr => played.every(
    num => !subarr.includes(num)
  )
);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to create a Set of `played` to avoid iterating it again and again:

```js
var matches = [[1,4],[3,1],[5,2],[3,4],[4,5],[2,1]];
var played = new Set([2,5]);
var out = matches.filter(a => !a.some(num => played.has(num)));
console.info(out)
```